# spring boot admin UI customization

Tags: spring

I would like to customize the spring boot admin ui to put some custom urls for healthcheck.I didn't find any examples on altering the UI like adding some tabs or putting some urls etx.
I found some documentation under http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/ but it wasn't helpfull.

Any help on this would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot admin uses `vue.js` for frontend. 
It is possible to add custom views to the ui. The views must be implemented as `Vue.js` components.

The JavaScript-Bundle and CSS-Stylesheet must be placed on the classpath at `/META-INF/spring-boot-admin-server-ui/extensions/{name}/` so the server can pick them up. The `spring-boot-admin-sample-custom-ui` module contains a sample which has the necessary maven setup to build such a module.

The custom extension registers itself by calling `SBA.use()` and need to expose a `install()` function, which is called by the ui when setting up the routes. The `install()` function receives the following parameters in order to register views and/or callbacks: